# WTForm used in two different views validate only using one view

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm having a problem using a WTForm in two different views. One view creates a new item, using the form data. The other view display information for items already in the database and the user should be able to update the form data from there.

I can create and view the items in the database. The problem is updating the information when in in the display view. The steps I take are something like:

1. Create a item in `/create`. Before saving to database check that the same ID is not already in database. If exists show a flash and do not permit saving the item. Reloading `/create`
2. To display information about a existing item the route `/display/<item>` call the database, populate the form and show the information using the same form.

#### Desired behavior

To update information when in `/display/<item>`. After updating any field data and pressing the submit button, the form should save to the database and reload `/display/<item>`.

#### Actual behavior

After pressing the submit button the form takes me back to the `/create` route, and performs the ID validation.

I don't understand why, being in a different view `/display/<item>`, the form's submit button takes me to the `/create` view.

---

The code goes something like this:

This is a simple form

```
    class ItemForm(FlaskForm):
        id = IntegerField("id", validators=[DataRequired()])
        name = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

With this I create a new item in the database, checking that the same Id is not already in the database:

```
    @app.route("/create", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def create():
        form = ItemForm()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            item = item = Item.query.filter(Item.id == form.id).first()
            # Check the same id is not already created
            if item is not None:
                flash('item already in database')
                return redirect(url_for("create"))

            item = Item()
            form.populate_obj(item)
            db.session.add(item)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for("display", item = form.id))
        else:
            return render_template("create.html", form=form)
```

And then after there is created items in the database i can call a display route. In this route I should be able to update the fields in the form and save it to the database. Whit out validating as the the same ID is already present in the database (I'm updating, no creating a new one).

```
@app.route("/display/<item>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def display(item):
    item = Item.query.filter(Item.id == item).first()
    form = ItemForm(obj=item)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(item)
        db.session.add(item)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("display", item=form.id))
    else:
        return render_template("display.html", form=form)
```

The problem is that when in the `/display/<item>` route, the submit button takes me back to the `/create` route. Performing the validations in there. Of course the item is already created in the database so I get the flash and I'm redirected to `/create`, when it should reload `/display/<item>`.

Could someone point me in the right direction, please. Thank you all!

Comment: Please add the form of your html, maybe the problem its on the action of your form

Comment: You just ask the right question. Checked python and js and assumed html was ok. When I was building the ```/create``` I added an action to the form and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, but @the_gañañufla asked the right question. The problems of coding alone.

I had added an action to the HTML  and i forgot to remove it.

I had

```html
<form id="form_item" action="{{ url_for('create') }}" class="form" method=post>
```

After correct it I have:

```html
<form id="form_product" action="" class="form" method=post>
```